# How do I get only scan just one class with Reflections

Tags: java, class

I have two classes `Foo` and `FooBar` both of which has some annotated fields. I would like to scan just `Foo` and not `FooBar` for the annotated fields. I am currently trying to use `org.reflections.Reflections` from https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections I have the following:

```
Set<Field> fields = new Reflections("my.package.Foo", new FieldAnnotationsScanner())
    .getFieldsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnatation.class);
```

However, this will also pick up fields in `FooBar` as it starts with the same prefix. How can I construct the `Reflections` object so as to just scan the one class?

Comment: What is `Reflections` ? Where does that class come from?

Comment: I have updated the questions.

Comment: [Class.getAnnotations()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotations--) or [Class.getAnnoation()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-)

Comment: it seems that Reflections only supports scanning of package, you can either scan the entire package and filter the results, or write your own method for scanning, like @JasonArmstrong suggested

Comment: Filtering is a good idea! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering the results works:

```
Set<Field> fields = new Reflections("my.package.Foo", new FieldAnnotationsScanner())
    .getFieldsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnatation.class)
    .stream().filter(field -> field.getDeclaringClass().equals(Foo.class))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```